# How do you load individual snippets of code in C#?

Tags: c#

This is probably a total noob question, but I'm trying to do a project to learn and find stuff out and ran into a snag:

In short, I have a bunch of different 'items,' each of which should have different behavior when used, meaning each would need its own little code snippet to describe how it works. Now, since there are a *lot* of these I felt that just loading all of them at once would be unnecessarily bloated, especially if I'd think of expanding this project. So, I thought I'd save each item individually, and while I got how save basic stuff with BinaryWriter, I'm not sure about how to load and save individual snippets of *code*..

**The actual question -** How do you save and load up individual snippets of C# code during runtime, for cases where loading up all of the snippets at once would just be completely unnecessary?

Comment: When you say that you *feel* that loading all of the code would be "unnecessarily bloated" - have you tried that? What are your performance criteria? Do you actually need snippets of source code, or do you just need to be able to run some subset of the total code? I would go for the *absolute simplest* approach to start with, and see whether that's actually too slow/large/whatever before you start getting into anything more complex.

Comment: Even though it is possible to compile code at runtime, it is generally not needed. I would suggest to just implement your "items" with an appropriate class structure and compile it directly into the application.

Comment: I think Jon's advice is the best place to start. However if your application is really big, you can split it up into multiple projects/assemblies, and this can result in some code being loaded later by the runtime. But I would first make sure its actually an issue.

Comment: Alright, I'm using this project 90% to learn new stuff, so I wanted to know if there was a more efficient way of going about it before going with the simpler solution. Thanks!